# How does haproxy treats conflicting options

Tags: logging, haproxy

In our current environment, the `haproxy.cfg` has two conflicting options:

```
option httplog
option tcplog
```

The resulting log (`/var/log/haproxy.log`) looks like:

```
Jul 16 09:39:05 campus-deploy haproxy[9862]: client_ip:client_port [16/Jul/2018:09:39:01.238] https~ backend/backend_server 0/1/3999 420
-- 12/12/0/0/0 0/0
```

To me, the log looks more like a [tcplog](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8.2.2) than a [httplog](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8.2.3) (even though the fields are not exactly the same as in the documentation and we do not have custom logs in place).

My questions is the following:

- How does haproxy treat conflicting options?

  - Does it take the first fitting option?
  - Does it apply the last option (overriding the previous option)?

Thanks in advance for you insights.

Comment: I don't see any obvious discrepancy from the documented format for `tcplog`.  Which part doesn't seem consistent to you?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Im referring to the [PDF memo] (https://cdn.haproxy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/aloha_load_balancer_memo_log.pdf) referenced on haproxy blog [HAProxy log customization] (https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-log-customization/) where field #3 (Syslog facility) is not present in our logs.

Comment: http://haproxy.com is not precisely the same as the open-source HAProxy, which is http://haproxy.org.  Commercial products may differ.  See http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#8.2, change '1.6' to your version as appropriate.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks for the tip. Actually, I didn't notice they were two different entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a `tcplog`.

In this case, it's a not exactly a "conflicting" option, its an option that allows itself to be overridden by a later declaration of a different option.

The last instance from top to bottom in the configuration is used.  Why this isn't an error is most likely related to the fact that one such option can be defined in the defaults section, only to be overridden in the individual proxy (frontend, listen, or backend) config.